# Como calcular a altura do Pixel com PHP

Tags: php, html, css, fpdf

Tenho uma tela na qual é gerado um relatório com uma quantidade limite de tabelas que não podem ser quebradas.

Tenho de fazer a paginação deste relatorio. Como calcular a altura dos pixes gerados ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com php acho que não é possível, amigo, pelo fato de ser server-side, mas com javascript é possível, dê um ID para a tabela e depois faça isso

```
var tabela = document.getElementById('tabela');
var altura = tabela.innerHeight;
alert(altura);
```

Comment: Não entendi o fato de ser negativado, sendo que não é possível fazer isto que você está pedindo com PHP, mesmo se pudesse, quando o CSS altera o estilo da tabela ela já pode ter mudado de tamanho.

Comment: Como pego esse valor do alert e atribuo em uma variável PHP?

Comment: Alex, quando a página é carregada, o PHP já foi executado e não vai adiantar nada você atribuir o valor da altura a uma variável PHP (a não ser que você faça uma nova requisição). Lembre-se que o PHP trabalha com DADOS. Não fique tentando reinventar a roda sendo que o javascript pode fazer isso pra você facilmente. Pense o seguinte o PHP te trás os dados e o javascript exibe esses dados da melhor forma possível (a forma que você desenvolver)

Comment: Se você já tem essa quantidade especifica que não pode ser quebrada, faça o estilo, veja quantos registros cabem no tamanho especifico e na hora do PHP apenas busque do banco a quantidade necessária.

Comment: Eu uso a biblioteca fpdf para gerar um arquivo pdf..porem não pode quebrar as linhas. Ou seja quando um bloco começa em um pagina tem de terminar nessa pagina. Na outra pagina tem de começar um novo bloco!!!

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema ? @alexjosesilva